# Sort by column using Specification in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, specifications

I have a dilemma on how to sort a column by the count of an entity from another table.

I have two entities

```
@Entity 
public class Plan {

   Long id;
   String name;
   PlanStatus status;
   LocalDateTime dateCreated;
   LocalDateTime lastUpdated;
}
```

```
@Entity 
public class Subscription {
   Long id;
   Plan plan;
```

Right now, I just directly passed the `Sort sort` for the repository implemented with `Pagable` (pageRequest)
`return smsPlanRepository.findAll(planSpecification, pageRequest);`

But is there a way where I could use `Specification` with the number of `Subcriber` of each `Plan`?

```
public Specification<Plan> hasSort(String sortBy) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    
        return //count of by Plan in Subscribers
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Besides pageable interface, spring specifications can also make use of sorting via the criteriaBuilder api as bellow:

```
public Specification<Plan> hasSort(String sortBy) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    
    query.multiselect(root.get("fields..."),
                criteriaBuilder.count(root.get("count_field")));

    query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(criteriaBuilder.count(root.get("count_field")));
    
     return //count of by Plan in Subscribers
    }
}
```